# Simultaneous log equations

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

I'm going through logarithms at the moment, and I can't solve this simultaneous equation:

$$\log x - \log 2 = 2\log y$$
$$x - 5y + 2 = 0$$

I've tried substituting both $x$ and $y$ to no avail:

$$\log \left(\frac{5y - 2}{2}\right) = \log y^2$$

or:

$$\log \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \log \left(\frac{x+2}{5}\right)^2$$

But I can't get passed that. Can someone point out what direction I need to go in?

Comment: $\log$ is injective.

Comment: @Zircht Can you define what you mean by "injective"?

Comment: It means that $\log(a)=\log(b)$ implies $a=b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the first equation we get $\frac x2=y^2$ so with the second equation we get

$$2y^2-5y+2=0,\quad y>0$$
can  you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks - how obvious! I feel very silly now :)

Comment: You're welcome. Never mind it's good to try!

Answer (score 1):

From
$$\log \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \log \left(\frac{x+2}{5}\right)^2 $$
you can raise to the power $10$ on both sides and get
$$
\frac{x}{2} = \left(\frac{x+2}{5}\right)^2.
$$